# how to populate a table of lookups using "Not in list"

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016, ms-access-forms

Table 1: My general information table

- Organization: A lookup/relationship field that defaults to "N/A" but pulls values from...

Table 2: Organization List

- No ID field, just the names of the organizations in the order which they were added

My data entry form has a combo box for organization and I would like it to update when I add an organization that hasn't been added before. I know I am supposed to use the "Not in List" event, but I don't know how to update the Organization list using this event. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `Limit To List` property of the combo-box is set to `Yes`.

Add a `On Not In List` event to insert the value to your source table when a new value appears:

```
Private Sub MyComboBox_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

    With DoCmd
        .SetWarnings False
        .RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Organization List](Organizations) VALUES ('" & NewData & "')"
        Response = acDataErrAdded
        .SetWarnings True
    End With

End Sub
```

Edit... nearly forgot... before I answer, what have you tried? :)

Edit 2... the example given is for a string value.  Remove the `'` from either side of `New Data` if it's a numeric value (but probably not if it's an organisation name).

Edit 3... The `INSERT` SQL is just one way of putting data into a table.  You may prefer the `RecordSet.Add` and `.Update` methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. as for your question:
I tried having a set list of values I entered and updating the list every time it said "This value is not in the list, would you like to update the list items?". I am not very good with access or VBA as I just started using them

I also tried your code and it didn't seem to change the organization list table. My current table has "N/A" as its one and only value (because it is the default). after typing "test" the only value in the table was "N/A"

Comment: I guess the first thing to check is whether the code actually executes - put a break point in the code by clicking in the border to the left of the line of code you're breaking on (a dot should appear in the border with the line of code highlighted).  If the code fires it will pause on that line - press F8 to step through the code line by line.  Hover your cursor over the `NewData` variable - does it show the value you entered?

Comment: Should the window with the code appear when I have a breakpoint? when adding a unique value, the code window does not appear

Comment: I made a mistake. I forget to change the limit to list to "Yes". After doing that, the code breaks at ".SetWarnings False" what could be wrong here? I do have the breakpoint set at .RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Organization list](Organizations) VALUES ('" & NewData & "')" the error box says "Run-time error '424': Object required

Comment: Not at my computer so can't test. You do have the `With DoCmd` before it? Try commenting out the two `.SetWarnings` lines (add a `'` at the start of the line). They just stop the query confirmation messages from appearing.  Hopefully the value gets added then we can worry about the warnings.

Comment: Good lord, I spelled "Do" as "Co". The value does show up in the table now. Thank you